# Is it possible to do nested spying with Mockito?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Let's assume I have an object like this:

```
public ClassA() {
   public void start() {
      ...
      ClassB something = getSomeStuff();
      ...
   }
  
   protected ClassB getSomeStuff() {
      return new ClassB(render, response);
   }
}
```

Then I'm trying to do some unit-testing like this where I do a spy on a method-call on a spied object:

```
@Spy private ClassA classA;
@Mock private ClassC classC;
...
@Test 
void test1() {
    ClassB classB = spy(classA.getSomeStuff());
    doReturn(classC).when(classB).getResults();

    classA.start();
}
```

When I run this test and it comes down to this last line, I can see in my debugger that it is not returning classC.

Is this because it is not possible to do nested spying? Or is somehting wrong in my setup? Or should I approach this differently?

---

Details:

- junit: 5.7.0
- mockito: 3.12.4

Comment: You can mock ClassB and make classA.getSomeStuff() return this mockClassB. on that you can return mock ClassC.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the implementation of `ClassA::getSomeStuff`. I suspect that this method returns a new instance of `ClassB` with every call. This would mess up the setup since a non-spy `ClassB` instance would be returned for the actual test.

Comment: @Turing85: Edited the code. And yes, it only returns a new instance.

Comment: Well that's the problem then. The 1st call (`ClassB classB = spy(classA.getSomeStuff());`) returns a `ClassB`-instance and the 2nd call (when the test is run, `ClassB something = getSomeStuff();`) returns another instance. This is a nice example of code that is hard to test. We could, of course, also mock the call of `classA::getSomeStuff` to return `classB`, but then the question is: what are we even testing? --- A general remark: whenever possible, we should use `when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(someResult)` instead of `doReturn(someValue).when(someMock).someMethd()`.

Comment: Consider creating a `ClassBFactory`, and inject that factory into `ClassA` so that `getSomeStuff()` delegates to the factory (rather than directly creating a new `ClassB` instance).  For the test, inject a mock factory which provides a mock of `ClassB`.

Comment: @Turing85: This is actually a portlet with 2-phase rendering where i try to test the doHeaders(renderRequest, renderResponse) phase. The problem is that the code now is creating elements on the renderRespose way down in ClassC. My collegues are saying that since the unittest for ClassA also should verify that we actually are creating elements on the response.
And when I do my unittest for ClassB, and do a spy from that level and down to ClassC it all works.

Answer (score 2):

When we look at the code presented, we see that calling `classA.getSomeStuff()` will return a new instance of `ClassB` with every call, i.e. `classA.getSomeStuff() == classA.getSomeStuff()` will evaluate to `false`.

What does that mean for our test setup? We construct a spy:

```
ClassB classB = spy(classA.getSomeStuff());
```

but this spy is never used. When we call `classA.start()`, it will call `classA.getSomeStuff()` again, and a new (non-spy) `ClassB`-instance is returned.

This is an example of code that is difficult to test: we have no easy way to control or verify the behaviour of the `ClassB`-instance used during the test. We normally avoid this problem by using the [Inversion of Control principle (`wikipedia.com`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). Whether this is applicable in this situation I cannot say. For this, I would have to see more of the code, and it would most probably be out of scope for StackOverflow.

As a quick and dirty fix, we can mock the call to `classA.getSomeStuff()` after we have created our mock:

```
@Spy private ClassA classA;
@Mock private ClassC classC;
...
@Test 
void test1() {
    ClassB classB = spy(classA.getSomeStuff());
    when(classB.getResults()).thenReturn(classC);
    when(classA.getSomeStuff()).thenReturn(classB);

    classA.start();
}
```

---

As an aside: When using mockito, we should prefer the form

```
when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(someResult);
```

over

```
doReturn(someResult).when(someMock).someMethod();
```

The former guarantees type safety at compile time, the latter does not. It is not always possible to use the former form (e.g. for methods returning `void` we have to use the latter form).

Comment: Tried this inversion of code and it still gives the same error.

Comment: As I said: to say whether IoC is applicable, I would have to see more code. The idea would be that the c'tor of `ClassA` has a parameter of `ClassB`, and this parameter is stored in a field. Method `getSomeStuff()` would then just call  `getResult()` on that field.

Comment: Like i wrote in the comment abvove.....  This is actually a portlet with 2-phase rendering where i try to test the doHeaders(renderRequest, renderResponse) phase. The problem is that the code now is creating elements on the renderRespose way down in ClassC. We are arguing at work about the fact that the unittest for ClassA also should verify that we actually are creating elements on the response (which is done in ClassC). 
When I do my unittest for ClassB, and do a spy from that level and down to ClassC it all works.